# Getting email and phone number from website and saving it to a file using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, macos

I have this script to collect information from the website and output them to a text file. It downloads the site then uses grep to extract information. I need to use formatting to output them as I wanted to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo Enter an url

read url

mkdir site
cd site
wget -r -l1 --follow-tags=a --no-check-certificate $url
grep -r -E -o -H "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b" * | sort -u >> ~/email.txt
grep -r -E -o -H "\(?[[:digit:]]{5}\)?[[:space:]]?[[:digit:]]{6}" * | sort -u  >> ~/phone.txt
cd ..
rm -rf site
```

When I run this I get an output like that :

```
www.example.com/en/contact:91112223334
...
www.example.com/en/contact:info@example.com
```

I want to make tabular format.

email.txt

| url | email |
| --- | --- |
| [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) | info@example.com |

phone.txt

| url | phone |
| --- | --- |
| [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) | 0 111 222 33 34 |

I need to format the phone numbers as shown in table. I've tried to use awk but I couldn't make it.

Comment: Have you try with `sed`? `sed 's/:/\t/g'`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I tried this `url=$(echo -n $URL | sed -rn 's/.*https?\:\/\/([a-z\.]+).*/\1/p')`